# Web Deploy add rewrite rule in parameter

Tags: parameters, msbuild, webdeploy

We build our web projects with MSBuild and create deploy packages on our Cruise Control build server. These packages then get deployed to various locations (Test, Stage, Prod).

We use Web.config transformations for settings regarding all environments and devide betwenn builds for development and release.

We then use parameters.xml to set environment specific details like connnection string, logging information and service endpoints.

But what if I want a rewrite rule only for one environment which will currently be deleted because web.config will be overwritten.

**UPDATE:**
As far as my tests revealed, it is not possible to set XML text as values. Something like this will fail:

```
<setParameter name="Additional Rewrite Rule" value="\<rule name="Redirect subdomain to sub-domain-purchase" stopProcessing="true"\>
                \<match url="(.*)" \/\>
                \<conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false"\>
                    \<add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="subdomain.hostname.com" \/\>
                \</conditions\>
                \<action type="Redirect" url="http://sub-domain.hostname.com/{R:0}" redirectType="SeeOther" \/\>
            \</\rule\>" />
```